# How to escape double quotes in as a parameter to an NUnit TestCase?

Tags: vb.net, nunit, escaping, testcase, double-quotes

I tried writing the following TestCase for an NUnit test written in VB.net:

```
<TestCase("FirstNode", "<node id=\"FirstNode\">")>
Public Sub GetNode_GivenSomeNodeId_ReturnCorrectNode(ByVal nodeId as String, 
                                            ByVal expectedXml as String)

    (Call the method under test and request the xmlNode with the provided id...)

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedXml, returnedXml)
End Sub
```

The xml-node passed as the second parameter to the testcase is not valid however, as this clearly is not the correct way to escape double quotes. I'm sure I can find a workaround in order to check that the method under test returns the expected XML-node, but I'm curious:

Is there some clever way to pass a string such as this, containing double quotes, as a parameter to an NUnit test?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The correct way to escape double-quotes in VB is by doubling the double-quotes:

```
<TestCase("FirstNode", "<node id=""FirstNode"">")>
```

Comment: I find this weird actually, the difference  when adding a + between the quotes is obviously big, it does not seem logical to do it this way, but then again, more things in vb.net aren't logical

Comment: Or use the Chr(34) so: <TestCase(Chr(34)FirstNodeChr(34), Chr(34)<node id=Chr(34)FirstNodeChr(34)>Chr(34)")>

Comment: @Fuzzybear - thanks, flashbacks to BASIC on the Spectravideo MSX.