# vb.net How do I write " in Replace(aString, """, "")?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to replace " with nothing.

```
bString = Replace(aString, """, "")
```

does not work.

It says 'sting constants must end with a double quote'

What do I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7726568/84206

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.Net, double quotes are escaped by doubling them: `""""`

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before with the character code -

```
bString = Replace(aString, chr(34), String.Empty)
```